# Unable to property copy query to a data table

Tags: c#, linq, filter, datatable

I'm using this query to filter some data with `groupby` "Client" + sum amount and to fill a datagrid.  I got an error in the `select` keyword. Any ideas how to fix this?

This is the code that I'm using:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> query = from p in data.AsEnumerable()           
         where (p.Field<string>("BS") == txtFilterbyBC.Text 
                && p.Field<string>("YEAR") == txtYear.Text
                && p.Field<string>("RM") == txtRM.Text)
                group p by p.Field<string>("Client") into g
                select new
                {
                   Name = g.Key,
                   Total = g.Sum(x => Convert.ToDouble(x.Field<double>("AMOUNT")))
                };

System.Data.DataTable boundTable = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
dataGridView1.DataSource = boundTable;
```

The error is:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?

Comment: What error did you get? Is this C#?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.DataRow>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Then I am adding the C# tag for you  you might get answers quicker if you add a language tag if the question is language specific

Answer (score 0):

The `CopyToDataTable` method that you are using is designed to take a sequence of data rows and convert it into a data table.  If the items in the sequence aren't already of type `DataRow` (or a more derived type) then it won't work, which is the case here.

While there are ways of converting that data to a data table, there's also no need.  Just bind the `DataGridView` directly to your query.  There's no need to wrap it all up in a DataTable.  Doing so is just unneeded effort.

If you actually did need a `DataTable` (but again, it doesn't appear that you do), then you can use [this other method](Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) to copy the data from a non-data row source into a `DataTable`.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that, I've used this syntax trying to groupBy. I know without this last operation I did get the rows. The question remains however, how can I then extract rows and groupby in the same time and fill into datagridview directly or through a datatable, any one could help ?